# erase a persistent drawRect

Tags: ios5, uiview, core-graphics, drawrect

I at last managed to get DrawRect that did not clear all the time  using
(I also have the setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES  )

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(drawingContext);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(drawingContext); 
    UIImage *uiImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(drawingContext, 4.0);
    if (draw)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawingContext, [UIColor  whiteColor] CGColor]);
    else
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawingContext, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(drawingContext,    lastPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a),  lastPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a)  );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(drawingContext, currPt.x - (31.0 / self.transform.a),  currPt.y - (31.0 / self.transform.a)  );
    CGContextStrokePath(drawingContext);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    [uiImage drawInRect: rect];

    lastPt = currPt;
}
```

This leaves behind a line at it is drawn
My problem is when draw is NO  [UIColor clearColor]   is NOT erasing  What am I supposed to use to erase ?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `clearColor` has an alpha of zero, drawing with it normally doesn't have any effect.  You need to set the context's blend mode to `kCGBlendModeCopy` to make it take effect.

However, it would be simpler to just set the context's blend mode to `kCGBlendModeClear` when you want to erase, and back to `kCGBlendModeNormal` when you want to draw:

```
if (draw) {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(drawingContext, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawingContext, [UIColor  whiteColor] CGColor]);
} else {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(drawingContext, kCGBlendModeClear);
}
```

Comment: @rob: using "kCGBlendModeClear" erases the drawing .. but it also clears the image set in the image view (Iam trying to draw on the image). Any ideas about this?